# How to speed up simple loop in python

Tags: python, optimization

I want to accelerate the speed of loop in python.
There is a code below.

```
for x in dpath.util.search(self.data, "**", yielded=True):
        self.contentsList.append(x)
```

dpath.util.search is generator.
how could I speed up this simple loop??

Answer (score 2):

Well, the loop itself is unnecessary; you could let Python do the looping & append work with a single function call instead of many calls with:

```
self.contentsList.extend(dpath.util.search(self.data, "**", yielded=True))
```

Comment: I don't know `dpath`, but if `yielded=True` is what makes it act as a generator, it's sometimes faster not to act as a generator when you're bulk `extend`ing, so you might drop that argument if it makes it return a `list`.

Comment: First, thank for your answer. I tested it, but unfortunately there is no enhancement of speeding up, I want to speed up nearly C code speed. I thought cython is the way to solve it, but I have no idea how to apply cython to this code. Could you give me any idea about cython?

Comment: have you looked at [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)?  Also I've had more success with [ObjectPath](https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath) than dpath though I can't comment on the relative speeds between the two

Comment: @FujiApple thx for your comments! I'll have a try using numba!